# Unable to pass options to \LoadClass{book} when using pgfopts for my own class

Tags: pgfopts

I'm writing a class for a course guide, and basing it on the standard `book` class. Following the answer by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) to [Passing (just) other options, when using pgfopts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166463/passing-just-other-options-when-using-pgfopts), I started working on my own class. Yet somehow, while it doesn't complain about the extra options, and seems to have the correct options when calling `LoadClass`, none of those options affect the behaviour of the `book` class.

```
\begin{filecontents}{courseguide.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{courseguide}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

%%%% PGF options
\def\Course@classoptions{10pt}

%% Academic year
\newcounter{AY}
\setcounter{AY}{\the\year}

\pgfkeys{
  /Course/.cd,
  %%% This is the academic year
  AY/.code=\setcounter{AY}{#1},
  AY/.default=\the\year,
  .unknown/.code={
    \message{mwe found unknown key: \pgfkeyscurrentname}
    \edef\Course@classoptions{\Course@classoptions,\pgfkeyscurrentname}
  }
}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/Course}

\message{MWE Current \\Course@classoptions: \Course@classoptions}

\LoadClass[\Course@classoptions]{book}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[AY=2026,letterpaper,landscape,12pt]{courseguide}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

The academic year is \theAY-{\the\numexpr\theAY+1}

\end{document}
```

Here's a non-working MWE. The options *appear* to be passed, but it's always in 10pt, a4, portrait. I expect this is trivial, but I'm stumped.

---

**Addendum.** After the first answer (which helps a lot) I'm puzzled by what happens if I remove the `\usepackage{showframe}` from the (fixed) test document. The printed content is still the same:

> The academic year is 2026-2027.
>
> The document uses paper of size W=11.00215 in, H=8.50166 in.
>
> The document font size is 12.

But the actual document is (by checking the PDF properties in evince) A4 paper.

[image: Conflict between dimensions in latex and evince]

If instead of removing that line I replace it with `\usepackage[noframe]{showframe}`, The dimensions and orientation are the same.

Comment: No, it is 12pt (as you can see in the `log`, because of loading `bk12.clo`). And it is letterpaper and landscape, but the standard classes do not setup, e.g., the PDF lengths on there own, so you need, e.g., to load a package, that do, to see it. For example add `\DocumentMetadata{}` before `\documentclass` or add `\usepackage{showframe}` and maybe add `in \csname f@size\endcsname{} on paper of size W=\the\paperwidth, H=\the\paperheight` to the test text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are some wrong assumptions in your questions.

It is a strange *feature* of the standard classes not to setup backend specific lengths for the paper size. So, e.g., using PDFLaTeX to compile

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

and

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{book}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

both would result in PDFs with the same document information about page size, usually (using `pdfinfo`):

```
Page size:       595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
```

Nevertheless, the documents would differ, as you can see, if you add more text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

vs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

So not to see the correct size in the PDF does not mean, that `book` has not processed options `letterpaper` (which is already the default of `book`) or `landscape`.

To see the real paper size in the PDF, you could either use the `pdfmanagement-testphase` (see the manual for more information), adding `\DocumentMetadata{}` before `\documentclass` or load a package like `hyperref` or `showframe`.

If you'll look into the font information of the generated PDF you would see (using `pdffonts`): `AKGSOO+CMR12`. The part `CMR12` means, that 12pt is used. And in the `log` file you would find, that `bk12.clo` is loaded, not `bk10.clo`. So your assumption about still using 10pt is also wrong.

To see the correct PDF dimension and also the used font size, I would recommend to use another test file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{courseguide.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{courseguide}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

%%%% PGF options
\def\Course@classoptions{10pt}

%% Academic year
\newcounter{AY}
\setcounter{AY}{\the\year}


\pgfkeys{
  /Course/.cd,
  %%% This is the academic year
  AY/.code=\setcounter{AY}{#1},
  AY/.default=\the\year,
  .unknown/.code={
    \message{mwe found unknown key: \pgfkeyscurrentname}
    \edef\Course@classoptions{\Course@classoptions,\pgfkeyscurrentname}
  }
}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/Course}

\message{MWE Current \\Course@classoptions: \Course@classoptions}

\LoadClass[\Course@classoptions]{book}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[AY=2026,letterpaper,landscape,12pt]{courseguide}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{printlen}
\begin{document}

The academic year is \theAY-{\the\numexpr\theAY+1}.

\uselengthunit{in}
The document uses paper of size W=\printlength{\paperwidth},
H=\printlength{\paperheight}.

The document font size is \csname f@size\endcsname.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the options are all processed as expected.

However, note, that options of `book` are processed in the order, they are defined not in the order they are used. So if you'd use:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{courseguide.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{courseguide}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

%%%% PGF options
\def\Course@classoptions{12pt}% CHANGED!!!

%% Academic year
\newcounter{AY}
\setcounter{AY}{\the\year}


\pgfkeys{
  /Course/.cd,
  %%% This is the academic year
  AY/.code=\setcounter{AY}{#1},
  AY/.default=\the\year,
  .unknown/.code={
    \message{mwe found unknown key: \pgfkeyscurrentname}
    \edef\Course@classoptions{\Course@classoptions,\pgfkeyscurrentname}
  }
}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/Course}

\message{MWE Current \\Course@classoptions: \Course@classoptions}

\LoadClass[\Course@classoptions]{book}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[AY=2026,letterpaper,landscape,10pt]{courseguide}% FONT SIZE OPTION CHANGED
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{printlen}
\begin{document}

The academic year is \theAY-{\the\numexpr\theAY+1}.

\uselengthunit{in}
The document uses paper of size W=\printlength{\paperwidth},
H=\printlength{\paperheight}.

The document font size is \csname f@size\endcsname.

\end{document}
```

You would still have 12pt, because `book` defines the font size options using:

```
\if@compatibility
  \renewcommand\@ptsize{0}
\else
  \DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\fi
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}
```

and therefore 12pt would be processed last always. So setting defaults in the definition of `\Course@classoptions` could be problematic.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I added an addendum to my question using your test file, for which there is (for me) a strange dependency on `\usepackage{showframe}`

Comment: @GTL I've explained that dependency already in my answer (and also in the comment). It is because, `book` does not set the backend dependent lengths. Some packages set them, e.g., `hyperref`, `graphicx` (and therefore `showframe`), `typearea` … and `pdfmanagement-testphase`.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood the dependencies.